# forcing to download mp3 link instead of streaming it

Tags: php

i been looking and i could not find a way to force to save a mp3 file ( from link )
i found this that works with the files on same host Like `x.mp3` or a/x.mp3

```
<?php
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    header("Content-type: octet/stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

but how can i do this for mp3 links which stream instead of downloading it ?
like

```
http://ahmusm.mubox.in/nevisande/aliz/mp3/1395/02/05/Beyonce%20-%20Hold%20Up.mp3
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML use:

```
<a download href="file.mp3">
```

In [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) it forces download.

This also allows you to avoid using PHP to serve that particular file. By default PHP prevents download resumption and makes serving relatively expensive for your server.

Comment: to use as button i used this and works great <a download href="x.mp3"><button type="button">Download</button></a> thanks

Comment: `<button>` is forbidden in `<a>` and may break it. Use `<a style="display:block;background:gray">` etc. to make the link look like a button.